# Client-Server architecture: Login system with JAVA

Tags: java, database, authentication, client-server

I have an assignment to realize a client-server based shop whose checkout system acts like a cashier desk in supermarket.  The main programming language is JAVA.

Server: I need to deploy locally a database (SQL) by using JDBC and Myadminphp (already done)

Client: There are two types of users: Cashier and Manager.  The Cashier is able to access only to `checkOut()` function where he makes queries to the database to do the checkout process for customers.  The Manager is able to access `getData()` to retrieve a table of available data in the shop and `addItem()` to permit re-stocking for a particular product.

My question is: Since I need to realize a way using JAVA language to create a login system in the client site (using Java GUI also) to do the login process in order to grant access to the functions for different types of user,  what kind of methods could I use to implement the login system?  And do I also need to implement the system by running another server rather than the one that keeps the database?

Comment: Are you allowed to use frameworks? If so, look up [Spring](https://spring.io/) and [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). Spring Security would offer a great way to manage your login system with different roles (Cashier, Manager).

Comment: "And do I also need to implement the system by running another server rather than the one that keeps the database?"  Are you saying your server now is just the database that the clients access directly via JDBC? That is risky. Much safer to go three-tier, and have an application server (your code) in between that decides who gets to access the database and how.

Comment: @oussama Thank you! Framework is acceptable. I am going to take a look on it, since this is the first time I have to do a complex assignment myself, it's quite a tough challenge at first :-)

Comment: @thilo Could you clarify "risky"?xD is that something that could do harm to the security part?

Comment: Someone with JDBC access can run any query against the database (not just what your application would issue). It is very hard to limit this to a secure level. A middle-tier application server will only allow a "whitelist" of queries.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to create a separate server to provide Identity and Access Management (IAM). You can take a look at spring-cloud-oauth2 and an API Gateway infront of it. For API Gateway spring-cloud-zuul is a better idea.

Comment: Do we have any kind of GUI support if I use the framework?

Comment: The specified frameworks are not having any GUI. Its all based on config files.

If you need GUI, I am not sure you can check with Kong for API Gateway, i think it is having GUI.

Answer (score 0):

1) problem of giving access can be solved by two ways one by using the built in frameworks like spring security or apache shiro. Other way is to verify the permissions and roles on your own by loading the union of permission available in the roles assigned to logged in user and make a check on the methods which you want to be in authorized access criteria. you can implement login using token based(oauth2.0) system.

2) Database should be deployed on server system so that multiple application instance can access to it.

Comment: 1) Thank you, might explain a little bit the difference (pros and cons) between the Spring security and Oauth2.0?

Comment: @Username00097 please refer the below links Pros and cons of oauth -  http://www.socialtechnologyreview.com/articles/oauth-pros-and-cons-oauth      Configuring oauth2 with Spring security http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs